# Falta la traduccion del cartel cuando el usuario no puede acceder al chat por no tener suficiente reputación

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-rechazado, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

Cuando los comentarios se hacen muy largo, y el sistema da la opción de iniciar una sala de chat para la pregunta, si el usuario que hizo la pregunta no llega a la reputación mínima aparece un cartel que dice:

[image]

> %s has only %d reputation, not yet enough to chat.

Tenemos que conseguir que dicha cadena pase a traducir.

### Editado

se reporto en MSE:

[messages from the chat system are not localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314001/141717)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este mensaje de error viene de bonfire (la aplicación de chat). Como el chat no está localizado, no podemos ajustarlo via transifex.

Podríamos parsear los mensajes de error que vienen del chat, pero... suena a una mala idea.

Comment: ouch... deberiamos elevar el problema por MSE?

Comment: podés probar, le veo pocas posibilidades

Comment: oki.. elevemos el problema.. sacatelo de encima... ;)

Comment: \o/ \o/ \o/ \o/